# How can I use Underscore.js templates in conjunction with EJS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, underscore.js, ejs

They both use the same syntax for inserting variables.  For example if I want the following

```
<%= username %>
```

In my Underscore, my main EJS breaks because it tries to replace username and no such variable exists in the main page.

Comment: Why do you need both?  And do the square brackets work, as mentioned here? http://code.google.com/p/embeddedjavascript/wiki/Testing

Comment: I'm using EJS with Backbone.js

Comment: are the square brackets working for you?

Comment: No.  I not only need a custom tag but I need to get EJS to ignore <% %>

Comment: review the new part of my answer please.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think square brackets will work in EJS by default:

```
[%= username %]
```

And if you need to get fancier, the EJS github page describes how to create custom tags:

```
var ejs = require('ejs');
ejs.open = '{{';
ejs.close = '}}';
```

- I think that 2nd "fancier" part might be specific to server-side applications

https://github.com/visionmedia/ejs

Using the client side GitHub example, you'd need to do syntax like this when you render:

```
var html = require('ejs').render(users, { open: "^%", close: "%^" });
```

Options are the 2nd parameter of the `render()`.

Answer (score 9):

I had this issue and thought I would share the solution I found for solving the issue client side. Here is how your change the escape regex (via underscore.js [docs](http://underscorejs.org/#escape)):

```
_.templateSettings = {
    interpolate : /\{\{(.+?)\}\}/g
};
var template = _.template( "{{example_value}}");
```

Changes the <%= %> to {{ }}.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue when I wanted to render the webpage using ejs template on back-end (express), meanwhile I had to use underscore template on front-end.

I tried Marc's answer but it doesn't help, I think it has been out of date to use in newer version. In newer version of ejs(mine is `2.3.3`), you can no longer use `ejs.open` and `ejs.close`, use **`ejs.delimiter`** instead.

I changed the delimiter to '$' in ejs so ejs would only handle with `<$ $>` tag to insert variables and take `<% %>` tag as meaningless syntax.

```
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
var ejs = require('ejs');
ejs.delimiter = '$';
app.engine('ejs', ejs.renderFile);
```

NOTE: I add the code above in `app.js` file in express applications and it worked fine, and if you want to use it on front-end, just pass `{'delimiter': '$'}` in `ejs.render(str, options)` as options argument.