# How to integrate Expressjs and UnderscoreJS

Tags: model-view-controller, node.js, express, underscore.js

I'm making an Expressjs app however I don't particularly want to use Jade. I installed UnderscoreJS successfully into my app so I can use its templating capabilities (as well as some of its other features).

My question is when I want to insert, for example, the current year into my html docs (  `#{+new Date().getFullYear()}` in Jade), where should I do so?
Is it possible to insert into the HTML file directly or should I set a variable equal to the result in the routes file and then send it to a `<%=year%>` tag in my html file?

Comment: have you considered using EJS?

Comment: I was hoping to have some of the other features of Underscore but having taken a second look at it, I may just settle on EJS. Still open to ideas though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per my comment, EJS would be a good option I think.
You can also use Underscore with EJS - [How can I use Underscore.js templates in conjunction with EJS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10282260/how-can-i-use-underscore-js-templates-in-conjunction-with-ejs)